# how to check if a specific user is signed into google hangout

Tags: google-plus

Is there an API call to check if a specific user (whose google+ id is known) is signed into Google Hangout or not ?

The application I am working on requires me to show a Google Hangout button to customer X only when customer Y is already logged into a Google Hangout.

I have already checked the People Google+ API as well as the Hangout API and I cannot find any call will provide me this info.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Thanks,